# Minitest shortened syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

The following is a Rails model test:

```
it "will respond to name" do
  @user.must_respond_to :name
end
```

In minitest, is there a way to shorten this syntax like this?

```
it { must_respond_to :name }
```

or even this?

```
it { must_respond_to (:name) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is recommended to do that, but maybe you can just do this:

```
alias :old_it :it
def it test_name = "", &pr; old_it(test_name){@user.instance_eval(&pr)} end
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are looking for us not possible with the assertions and expectations as defined by methods in minitest. What you want is matchers. Take a look at the minitest-matchers project which enables the syntax you are after.

https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-matchers